# Update state from OnPress if action is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to update a constant to be true if user press Yes on an AlertIOS window.

But can't get it working currently its built as

```
deleteDeck = () => {
    const {id} = this.props
    const executeRemoval = false
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      AlertIOS.alert(
        'Remove Deck',
        'Are you sure you want to delete this deck?',
        [
          {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
          {text: 'Yes', onPress: () =>  executeRemoval = true},
        ],
      )
    }
```

And if the user press Yes const executeRemoval should now be true and by that entering

```
{executeRemoval &&
      removeDeck(id)
      .then(() =>  this.props.deleteDeck(id))
      .then(() =>  this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
          ]
        })))
      }
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how to get this behvior working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple function that is going to handle the action you want to run.

**Example**

```
executeRemoval = () => {
  const { id } = this.props;
  removeDeck(id)
  .then(() =>  this.props.deleteDeck(id))
  .then(() =>  this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
    ]
  })))
}

deleteDeck = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    AlertIOS.alert(
      'Remove Deck',
      'Are you sure you want to delete this deck?',
      [
        {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
        {text: 'Yes', onPress: this.executeRemoval },
      ],
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a stateful component and save the current state of executeRemoval in it.

```
class yourClass extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            executeRemoval = false
        }
    }
}
```

in your onPress event you do the following:

```
onPress={() => this.setState({ executeRemoval: true })}
```